# Calling methods during a constructor call

Tags: java, coding-style

I've been going through the Android development tutorials and I see a lot of calls like this:

```java
String date = new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear).append(" "));
```

Seems like a nice shorthand way of doing things, but is this really a good practice? Will this have any negative side effects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

The code does not call methods during the call to the constructor. It calls methods on the object returned by the constructor, *after* the constructor has completed.

Each of those method calls finish with `return this` and that is the key. That's what allows the calls to be chained together.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had never heard of this term before, but had seen it and thought it weird.

Comment: There's a time and a place for Fluent, but it's probably not here. Jon explains why simple concatenation is better than append.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's fine - but it's not clear what you're concerned about. If you think that that's calling the `append` method during the `StringBuilder` constructor, it's not. This code is equivalent to:

```
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
tmp = tmp.append(mMonth + 1);
tmp = tmp.append("-");
tmp = tmp.append(mDay);
tmp = tmp.append("-");
tmp = tmp.append(mYear);
tmp = tmp.append(" ");
String date = tmp.toString();
```

Each call to `append` will actually return `this` in `StringBuilder`, but in other similar APIs the object may be immutable and each method will build a *new* object and return that... the calling code would look the same.

(I assume the real code had a `toString` call, of course, otherwise it wouldn't have compiled.)

Note that this is actually equivalent to:

```
String date = (mMonth + 1) + "-" + mDay + "-" + mYear + " ";
```

... which is really rather more readable than the original code, *and does the same thing*. The Java compiler will use `StringBuilder` under the hood anyway. Of course, you should really be using `SimpleDateFormat` or Joda's `DateTimeFormatter` to format dates, of course...

Comment: The StringBuilder append() method is the equivalent of concatenation of String object ?  I though that using StringBuilder was better/faster than a simple String date = month + "-" + day

Comment: @Nettogrof: String concatenation is *implemented* using `StringBuilder`. Lots of people use `StringBuilder` when they shouldn't, because they don't understand how string concatenation works :(

Comment: Thanks for the info. This StringBuilder example was just the most recent usage I saw.

Comment: @Dopyiii: It's a common one, but it's worth knowing about the difference between the "builder" pattern where each method returns "this", and other fluent interfaces which don't require mutability.

Answer (score 2):

Negative side effects include:

- Significantly higher WTFs per Second
- Angry fellow programmers
- Much harder to read code

That being said... there are cases where some methods in your code might almost always be called immediately which make sense.  If you are in love with doing this I would say definitely no more than 1 extra method call, but in general I would still recommend against it.

Answer (score 1):

No negative side affects, just makes it harder to read. A lot of developers go by the practice of the 'less code the better'.

Answer (score 0):

Fluent interface or not, in this case I'd prefer something like:

```
String date = String.format("%d-%d-%d ", mMonth+1, mDay, mYear);
```

Shorter, better to read.